# How to use ViewPager with NavigationDrawer in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabhost, android-navigation

I am trying to use in the same activity a NavigationDrawer and a ViewPager and it doesn't work correctly. I'm following the [developer google tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) I want to have three tabs, each one will show a different ExpandableList if it was selected. Currently I get the NavigationDrawer and the ExpandableList working fine, however the TabBar and de ViewPager doesn't manage the swipe and click events.

Could anyone help me? I've been reading and searching for ages!!

My main Activity HomeActivity is like this:

```
public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{
    // ExpandableList
    private ArrayList<String> parentItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Object> childItems = new ArrayList<>();

    // SlideMenu
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // Declaraciones Pager
    AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        ///// EXPANDABLELISTVIEW PART /////
        ExpandableListView expandableList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
        expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
        expandableList.setClickable(true);
        setGroupParents();
        setChildData();
        MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(parentItems, childItems);
        adapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);
        expandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
        expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        /////// ACTIONBAR PART///////////
        ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
        TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        mTitleTextView.setText("Título");
        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        /////// NAVIGATION DRAWER PART////////
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.prueba_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                //getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                //getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
//        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
//            selectItem(0);
//        }

        ////////////PART VIEWPAGER///////////////

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
        // of the app.
        mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Specify that the Home/Up button should not be enabled, since there is no hierarchical
        // parent.
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

        // Specify that we will be displaying tabs in the action bar.
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener for when the
        // user swipes between sections.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // When swiping between different app sections, select the corresponding tab.
                // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
                // Tab.
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
            // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
            // listener for when this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }


    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        //boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        //menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //boolean res = false;
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add:
                Toast.makeText(this, "add element", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.search:
                Toast.makeText(this, "search a text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.edit:
                Toast.makeText(this, "edit a element", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.delete:
                Toast.makeText(this, "delete a element", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Toast.makeText(this, "acction settings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        //TODO
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Toast.makeText(this, "elemento 0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(this, "elemento 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(this, "elemento 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


    public void setGroupParents() {
        parentItems.add("Androwwid");
        parentItems.add("Core Java");
        parentItems.add("Desktop Java");
        parentItems.add("Enterprise Java");
    }

    public void setChildData() {

        // Android
        ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<>();
        child.add("Core");
        child.add("Games");
        childItems.add(child);

        // Core Java
        child = new ArrayList<>();
        child.add("Apache");
        child.add("Applet");
        child.add("AspectJ");
        child.add("Beans");
        child.add("Crypto");
        childItems.add(child);

        // Desktop Java
        child = new ArrayList<>();
        child.add("Accessibility");
        child.add("AWT");
        child.add("ImageIO");
        child.add("Print");
        childItems.add(child);

        // Enterprise Java
        child = new ArrayList<>();
        child.add("EJB3");
        child.add("GWT");
        child.add("Hibernate");
        child.add("JSP");
        childItems.add(child);
    }

    public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    // The first section of the app is the most interesting -- it offers
                    // a launchpad into the other demonstrations in this example application.
                    return new DummySectionFragment();

                default:
                    // The other sections of the app are dummy placeholders.
                    Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    return fragment;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Section " + (position + 1);
        }
    }
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_dummy, container, false);
            Bundle args = getArguments();
//            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
//                    getString(R.string.dummy_section_text, args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

My activity_home.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="com.example.julio.listviewactionbar.Fragment_A"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_explist"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_explistview" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#111"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your activity_home.xml as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_explist"
            android:name="com.example.julio.listviewactionbar.Fragment_A"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_explistview" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

or

Use ViewPager logic in fragment

Comment: I've use your code but inflating others layouts because the problem now is the ExpandableListView. I can't show it inside the ViewPager and I don't really know hot to set the data of the adapter.

Comment: where is R.id.expandableListView1 in activity_home?

Answer (score 0):

Using DrawerLayout as the root element in your xml and ViewPager inside it as the first child should do it . I had the same thing done few days back.

Source - [Navigation drawer and view pager in same activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512241/navigation-drawer-and-view-pager-in-same-activity)

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that the DrawerLayout is stealing touches from the viewpager. When you swipe is the DrawerLayout coming out instead of the viewpager moving?

If this is the case then you need to extend DrawerLayout and ignore touches or extend the viewpager and have it request it's parent not disallow touch events.

Here is an example of what I think you're trying to do but with viewpagers inside viewpagers:
https://github.com/willowtreeapps/OAK/blob/master/oak-demos/src/oak/demo/widget/ParentSwipingViewPagerActivity.java

https://github.com/willowtreeapps/OAK/blob/master/oak-library/src/main/java/oak/widget/ParentSwipingViewPager.java