# How to implement navigation drawer with viewpager(having 3 tabs) in a single activity using material design?

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

I am new to android.I am trying to implement navigation drawer with viewpager and here the viewpager contains tablayout with three tabs in a single activity. I dont know how to do this. Do provide me proper solutions and also give some knowledge of how to do this.

Comment: [navigation-drawer-and-view-pager-in-same-activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512241/navigation-drawer-and-view-pager-in-same-activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this tutorial for your requirement this will produced like given image.

As you mentioned you are beginner to android then i suggest you follow complete tutorial.

[**Here is the Link**](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)
[image: Tabs look]